# Writing CSV in perl

Tags: perl, csv

I am parsing a html file and writing the source codes in separate cells by using the code:

```perl
open(MYFILE ,">>Test.csv");
print MYFILE qq|"$name","$table","$picture"\n|;
close MYFILE;
```

where the variable $table contains the content below::

```html
<table cellspacing=0" cellpadding="0" style="text-align: center;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="middle" class="td1">
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"><b><i><u><font size="5">Brand New in Package 64 GB Black/Silver USB 2.0 Flash Drive</font></u></i></b></span></p>
<ul class="ul1">
<li class="li2">Do not be fooled by the low price! The flash drives are EXCELLENT quality and I can assure you that you will be more than pleased</li><li class="li2">True Capacity</li>
<li class="li2">&nbsp;I am the fastest seller you will find and having your item shipped to you as fast as possible is my first priority</li>
<li class="li2">Most purchases will be shipped within 24 hours if ordered Monday - Friday</li>
<li class="li2">If you have any questions please feel free to ask!</li></ul></td></tr></tbody></table><center><br></center><center><br></center><center><font size="7" color="#00429a">Need more space? Check out my 128 GB Listings for as low as </font><font size="7" color="#ad001f"><b><u>$33.99</u></b></font><font size="7" color="#00429a">!!</font></center><p></p>"
```

which is making the CSV to occupy and overlapping the next cells. How can i make them to print in only one cell?

**Update**

@TLP Thanks but if i use this code

```perl
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
open my $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "Test.csv" or die "Test.csv: $!";
$csv->print ($name,$table);
close $fh;
```

its still showing an error as "Expected fields to be an array ref"

**Update**

Thanks SzG, I have another doubt how can i add a newline to it, i want to print it in row by row, if i use

```
$csv->print($fh,["\n"]);
```

its still not working as expected. i think i am wrong in some where

Comment: use [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV)?

Comment: You have the wrong parameters for Text::CSV::print. Try `$csv->print($fh, [ $name, $table ])`

Comment: Have a look at [Text::CSV::Encoded](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-Encoded-0.22/lib/Text/CSV/Encoded.pm) ...

Comment: For the newlines, add `$csv->eol("\r\n")`

Comment: The `eol` option can also be specified in the call to Text::CSV constructor: `my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, eol => "\r\n" } );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was suspicious that you never used the opened $fh filehandle. And yes, csv_print needs a filehandle and an array-ref.

In your original code it seemed you wanted to *append* to an existing CSV file `open(MYFILE ,">>Test.csv")`. So I changed the new code that way as well.

```
$csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();                      
open $fh, ">>:encoding(utf8)", "Test.csv" or die "Test.csv: $!";         
$csv->print($fh, [$name, $table]);                                       
close $fh;
```

Comment: Thanks SzG, I have another doubt how can i add a newline to it, i want to print it in row by row,
if i use 
`$csv->print($fh,["\n"]);`
its still not working as expected.
i think i am wrong in some where,.