# Is there a cell length limit writing CSV files with Text::CSV?

Tags: perl, csv

Linking to this question
[Writing CSV in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828903/writing-csv-in-perl)

I am parsing a content from html file and writing it in csv by using Text::CSV; which was working well.

But while the content size had over 130000+ characters, its getting overlapped or only partial content is written in the cell.

is that anything with the cell character limit range in a csv ?

Please give me some suggestion.

Update

i use this code to print the csv.
`$csv->print($fh, [$name, $table]);`

if the variable contains character '[',']' it get overlapped to next cells.

**Update**

From this link

I am trying to write the content inside the <\Description> Tag which have a large content.

Comment: do you mean 130000+ characters in a single value? Are you sure CSV is the most appropriate format for storing the data?

Comment: yes, all those characters are stored in a single variable.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried making a CSV file with a large single value of a character that is definitely "safe" (in case it's some problem with escaping or new lines)? for example write a cell with a value of `'a' x 140_000` and see if that gets truncated

Comment: @plusplus Even if i copy and paste it manually ,its not working in csv.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem *was* with Excel. The actual CSV file is correct, but according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3), Excel cannot read more than 32767 characters in a single cell:

> Total number of characters that a cell can contain: 32,767 characters

You could try other editors like:

- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)
- [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/CSV_files.html)
- [CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/)

At least one of them should work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks Sundar, But i does not mean this. I meant that the values are occupying the next cell , it getting broken and added to the near cells.

Comment: Ah, then the split itself is happening wrongly, probably a mistake in the HTML parsing code. Are you working on website scraping? My email ID is in my profile, if you shoot me a mail I can try and help your situation.

Comment: Even if i copy and paste the content manually ,its not working in csv

Comment: Better email me with exactly what you're doing, where you're pasting it to and how you're trying to read it, to the email ID you get when you click on my name. Once we determine what the problem is I'll update the answer with relevant solution for the sake of others.