# Scrapy - Messy text in a csv format

Tags: csv, text, scrapy

I am successfully extracting the text I need from a list of websites. The issue is when I am saving it in a csv format some of the rows gets messy because of long texts and breaks between rows within the text.
For example:

(couldn't upload the image :( )

So the lines starting with 0s/1s are of different websites but the last website in this image is starting several new rows in the csv file. This blocks me from continuing with the text analysis.

Any help will be highly appreciated as couldn't find a solutions so far.

Many thanks

Edit - adding code:
neither this line:

```
data = "".join(sel.select("//body//text()").extract()).strip()
```

nor this code line:

```
data = " ".join(" ".join(sel.select("//body//text()").extract()).strip().split())
```

didn't work

Comment: could you add some more details about that extracted text or provide some sample link and entities you are extracting from that page ?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the new line characters and all by performing both `join()` and `split()` on that given text. Before yielding the items make sure that you have properly cleaned the extracted text.

Suppose I want to fetch some sports news of the following [url](http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/sport/cricket/article4430493.ece), and will be look like this,

```
In [1]: text = response.xpath('//div[@id="page-1"]/p//text()').extract()

In [2]: text 
Out[2]: 
[u'\nThe retirement of Jonathan Trott from international cricket last night cast \nfurther doubt on the position of Peter Moores, who admitted he was uncertain \nabout his own future as head coach. The decision to recall Trott as an \nopening batsman for the series against West Indies, 18 months after his \nbreakdown in Australia, backfired spectacularly as England slid to a defeat \nin Bridgetown on Sunday that enabled the home side to level the Test series \n1-1.\n',
 u'\nThe defeat in Bridgetown added to the pressure on Moores after a disastrous \nWorld Cup earlier this year. The head coach conceded yesterday that']

In [3]: cleaned_text = ' '.join(' '.join(text).split())

In [4]: cleaned_text 
Out[4]: u'The retirement of Jonathan Trott from international cricket last night cast further doubt on the position of Peter Moores, who admitted he was uncertain about his own future as head coach. The decision to recall Trott as an opening batsman for the series against West Indies, 18 months after his breakdown in Australia, backfired spectacularly as England slid to a defeat in Bridgetown on Sunday that enabled the home side to level the Test series 1-1. The defeat in Bridgetown added to the pressure on Moores after a disastrous World Cup earlier this year. The head coach conceded yesterday that'
```

hope this might help

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I'm sorry for not copying my code at first but here it is:
data = "".join(sel.select("//body//text()").extract()).strip()
and after your suggestion I changed it to:
data = " ".join(" ".join(sel.select("//body//text()").extract()).strip().split())
Unfortunately still causing the same problem (though in a bit friendlier way)

Comment: can I get the url please ?

Comment: Still doesn't work though I think I found the problem - cell length limit in a CSV file:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842866/is-there-a-cell-length-limit-writing-csv-files-with-textcsv
will try to break / cut the text after exceeding this limit. Thanks