# csv cell contents need not shift in another cell if cell length goes beyond 32767 characters

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am writing contents in csv file format using python3.11.7, whenever the cell contents crossed the limit of 32760, remaining contents shift to another cell. I would like to keep the contents in the same cell whether its more than 32767 characters long.

I used the function csv.field_size_limit() to increase the number of characters stored in csv's cell.

But it is not fixing the issue, please see my code below:

```
import csv

csv.field_size_limit(2147483647)
with open(FilePath, 'a',newline='') as writecsvfile:
  csvwriter = csv.writer(writecsvfile)

for row_data in rows:
  csvwriter.writerow(row_data)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in anticipation.

Default is 131072 i.e 128k limit set in csv/excel

Comment: How are you determining that "remaining contents shift to another cell"?

Comment: before writing them in csv, I had kept all the data some where for tracking purpose

Comment: I meant, after you write the CSV, do you read it back in with Python and check? If so, do you have the code for how you did that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063936/csv-error-field-larger-than-field-limit-131072)

Comment: @Joe : If we view the content in editor++, shifting is not happening. Only, in excel application we can see the contents shifted to another cell whenever , it reach the limit of 32760, its moving the content into next cell with the remaining characters. My concern is to fix this limitation of displaying all the contents in same cell when I open the csv file in excel application

Comment: @ Emidio Neto: I am not getting any such error of "_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)" . My issue is displaying the content in the same cell using excel application when contents length is more than 32760, which is the limitation of excel application.

Comment: @Vicky, that's exactly what I suspected. Your question is not about Python. It's about MS Excel.

Comment: @ Joe: I thought we can fix the limitation or some workaround using Python, Any suggestions or options, need your direction to fix it, if possible?

Comment: Python cannot make MS Excel behave differently. Python can write a CSV with as many characters per cell as you want, but MS Excel cannot correctly read the CSV which exceeds ***its*** limitations. Do you need to use MS Excel?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18847363/6394617) answer to the same question in perl.

Comment: @Joe: Yeah , We are using excel for viewing the report generated using Python. Its still a limitation in excel, I saw the people asking for similar kind of concern on github,microsoft blog as well. Why this limitation still exists in excel which was raised years back. Anyway, thanks for your support